# Truly finding the "next" answer in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, search, iterator

I've run into situation where I need to find the next index of a list of dictionaries after a certain point.

So far I've only had to find uniquely identified elements by name, so I have used `next(x for x in list if x[prop] == search_term)`. But now I need to not only find a unique element, but find a specific element after a specified point in a list (a point that I may know by number or I may have to find as well, like finding the second "red" element after the first "red" element).

Not finding any built-in function in documentation and forums and stackoverflow, I decided I should build my own function. This was my first attempt:

```
def search_dict(my_dict, current_position, search_prop, search_term):
try:
    return next(index for (index, d) in enumerate(my_dict[current_position:]) if search_prop in d if d[search_prop] == search_term) + current_position
except StopIteration:
    return None
```

I exchanged `my_dict` for `my_dict[current_position:]` to only pass a subset of the code, and then add current position back onto the value to return the index of the whole list. Here is a test list:

```
a = [{"name":"A","color":"red"},{"name":"B","color":"blue"},{"name":"C","color":"red"},{"name":"D","color":"blue"},{"name":"E","color":"green"},{"name":"F","color":"green"}]
```

and to test my function:

```
print(search_dict(a, search_dict(a, 0, "color", "blue"), "color", "red"))
#this should find the first "blue" element at index 1 and then return the next "red" at 2
print(search_dict(a, search_dict(a, 0, "color", "red"), "color", "red"))
#this should find the first "red" element at index 0 and then return the next "red" at index 2
print(search_dict(a, search_dict(a, 0, "name", "D"), "color", "red"))
#this should find the "D" element and then go to the end of the list returning 'None'
print(search_dict(a, 0, "color", "blue"))
#should return 1
print(search_dict(a, 0, "color", "red"))
#should return 0
```

actual output:

```
2 #corrent
0 #incorrect
None #correct
1 #correct
0 #correct
```

They are all correct except the second one; it returns 0 for the first red instead of returning 2 for the second red. I tried multiple things to fix this, and I realized that I wanted the code to not output `None` at the end of the list but to "wrap" around and out the first element. So I rewrote the function like this:

```
def search_dict(my_dict, current_position, search_prop, search_term):
new_dict = [x for (x, d) in enumerate(my_dict) if search_prop in d if d[search_prop] == search_term] 
try:
    return next(x for x in new_dict if x > current_position)
except StopIteration:
    return next(x for x in new_dict)
```

I first had it compile a list of all the index points pertaining to the search criteria then had it return the next index greater than the current position. the output:

```
2 #correct
0 #incorrect
0 #correct
1 #correct
2 #incorrect <- this I fixed by changing the operator to if x >= current_position
```

Sadly the only one that is a problem is the 2 test, and that one is most important. trying to find the second or third `'x'` after an `'x'`.

I added an extra test, looking for the second green, which should be at index 5. Instead it returns 4.

**Partial solve**: The numbers return correctly if I change the operator back to `>` and add an empty element to the front of the list.

Comment: Note that `next` accepts a second argument, so that you don't have to write the `try: ... except`. Just do: `next((x for x ...), the_default)` and it will return `the_default` when getting a `StopIteration`.

Comment: I don't have clear what you are trying to do. Why return `0` in the third case? (when it first returned `None`)?

Comment: @Bakuriu, because after 'D', there is no red color.

Comment: So instead of `None` you simply want to always return `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of problem is always fiddly. You need to be very clear in your head what you want search dict to do: Return the location of the found item or return the new starting point. The results are failing as you are confusing the purpose of the return value of the function for example:

```
def search_dict(my_dict, current_position, search_prop, search_term):
    for i in range(current_position,len(my_dict)):
        if search_term== my_dict[i][search_prop]:
            return i
    return 

print(search_dict(a, search_dict(a, 0, "color", "red"), "color", "red"))
```

treats the return function as the location of the found array so it is inconsistent for the outer and inner functions to be 0 and 3. They have to be 1 and 3 or 0 and 0. You can mend you inputs accordingly (as shown)

```
print(search_dict(a, search_dict(a, 0, "color", "red")+1, "color", "red"))  
=2
```

EDIT:

OK, here is a better way to demonstrate the above. I have added a default argument to the method (Start_From_Next_Index). This does what it says on the tin, if it is set to true then the search will begin from the field you call 'current position' +1. However, obviously when you being the chain, you do want to check the zero position. Therefore, you want this field to be false whenever you are initialising you chain, and true when you are feeding the function back in, so it doesn't get stuck and find the same value again.

As a demo, check out this 3 chain example

```
a = [{"name":"A","color":"red"},{"name":"B","color":"blue"},{"name":"C","color":"red"},
{"name":"D","color":"blue"},{"name":"E","color":"green"},{"name":"F","color":"green"},
                                                {"name":"F","color":"red"}]

def search_dict(my_dict, current_position, search_prop,
                  search_term,Start_From_next_index=True):

    if Start_From_next_index==True:
        current_position+=1
    for i in range(current_position,len(my_dict)):
        if search_term== my_dict[i][search_prop]:
            return i
    return 



print(search_dict(a,
        search_dict(a,
            search_dict(a, 0, "color", "red",Start_From_next_index=False),
                                            "color", "red"), 
                                                "color", "red"))  
>>6
```

Comment: I'm confused, are you suggesting that there's no way to resolve this in a way that is uniform?

Comment: there will be a good way to do what you want to do for sure. But you have to make sure that the output for the function is consistent with the field 'current position'. I am at work now, but if I get a chance during the day I will see if I can suggest a better solution and edit my post. I am really saying something similar to Chris Clarke, but maybe less clearly.

Answer (score 1):

How about this code:

```
def search_dict(my_dict, current_position, search_prop, search_term, is_same_term=False):
    try:
        result = [dct.get(search_prop)
                  for dct in my_dict[current_position:]].index(search_term)

    if is_same_term:
        lst[lst.index(search_term)] = ''

        result += current_position
    except:
        result = None
    return result
```

and the test result:

```
>>> 
>>> a = [{"name":"A","color":"red"},
     {"name":"B","color":"blue"},
     {"name":"C","color":"red"},
     {"name":"D","color":"blue"},
     {"name":"E","color":"green"},
     {"name":"F","color":"green"}]

>>> search_dict(a, 0, "color", "blue")
1
>>> search_dict(a, 0, "color", "red")
0
>>> search_dict(a, 1, "color", "red")
2
>>> search_dict(a, 1, "color", "green")
4
>>> print(search_dict(a, search_dict(a, 0, "name", "D"), "color", "red"))
None
>>> print(search_dict(a, search_dict(a, 0, "name", "A"), "name", "A", True))
None
>>> print(search_dict(a, search_dict(a, 0, "color", "blue"), "color", "blue", True))
3
>>>
```

Hopes this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately running it through my test produced the same result. searching for a "color":"red" after a "color":"red" still returns the index of the first "red"

Comment: Thanks again, it looks more promising, except now the line for searching for "red" after "red" returns as "None." print([search_dict(a, search_dict(a, 0, "color", "red"), "color", "red", True)])

Answer (score 1):

```
search_dict(a, 0, "color", "red")
```

returns 0, so your second test is calling exactly the same function.

```
my_dict[0:] == my_dict
```

you perhaps need to call

```
print(search_dict(a, search_dict(a, 0, "color", "red") + 1, "color", "red"))
```

either that or your function needs to use `current_position + 1`

Comment: I've tried current position + 1. The results are similarly, slightly off.
1 
1 
None 
0 
1

Answer (score 0):

Ok I believe I found a solution, though I do not know if it is the best solution, I'll have to implement it more practically in my project.

I figured out what was happening, I was starting at the beginning of the list which is zero and I was asking it to find a number initially at greater than the current position, 2 > 0 the first red it was finding was at 2, because of the looping feature the next red it found was at the beginning = 0. I decided to try starting each search off before the list at -1, and all my current tests returned correct! (I don't know why >= wasn't working.) So I modified the function by giving "current_position" a default value of -1, like so:

```
def search_dict(my_dict, search_prop, search_term, current_position= -1):
    try:
        new_list = [x for (x, d) in enumerate(my_dict) if search_prop in d if d[search_prop] == search_term] 
        result = next(x for x in new_list if x > current_position)
    except:
        result = next(x for (x, d) in enumerate(my_dict) if search_prop in d if d[search_prop] == search_term)
    return result
```